# Free Flarum Imgur extension requires Client ID

Tags: image

I wish to add Imgur to Free Flarum. Free Flarum has an Imgur extension. To activate this I require a Client ID. I signed up to Imgur but I cannot locate how to set this up or how to retrieve this. Can you advise? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register an application. You can visit https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient to register your application. After registering your application, you will be able to get your ClientID.